# PHP Function Crashing WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently made a calculator for my gaming website although having some issues with the PHP and wordpress. I was hoping to put the calculator directly onto the website but as I have found out you have to call the functions with PHP (and I am clueless about PHP).

When I run it locally (not with PHP but HTML / JS / CSS in one file), it works perfectly.

This is the code I put at the bottom of my functions.php found in the theme files which gives me a fatal error:

```
function enqueue_custom_calculator_assets() {
    // Enqueue styles
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-calculator-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/Custom/troopRss.css');
    
    // Enqueue scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-calculator-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/Custom/troopRss.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

    // Enqueue jQuery from the WordPress core
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_calculator_assets');

function custom_calculator_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering
    ?>
    <div class="calculator">
        <div class="inputs">

            <div class="total-container">
                <label class ="output-label" for="Food">Food</label>
                <label class ="output-label" for="Wood">Wood</label>
                <label class ="output-label" for="Stone">Stone</label>

                <input type="text" id="Food" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
                <input type="text" id="Wood" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
                <input type="text" id="Stone" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">


                <label class ="output-label" for="Ore">Ore</label>
                <label class ="output-label" for="Gold">Gold</label>
                <label class ="output-label" for="ower">Power</label>

                <input type="text" id="Ore" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
                <input type="text" id="Gold" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
                <input type="text" id="Power" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
            </div>
            

            <br><br>
            <button type="button" id="newTroopButton">New Troop</button>

            <div id="troopList">

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered content
}
add_shortcode('custom_calculator', 'custom_calculator_shortcode');
```

It gives the error message:

```
[29-Aug-2023 13:04:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "enqueue_custom_calculator_assets" not found or invalid function name in /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#1 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#2 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php(2225): do_action('wp_enqueue_scri...')
#3 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): wp_enqueue_scripts('')
#4 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#5 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#6 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php(3053): do_action('wp_head')
#7 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/template-canvas.php(17): wp_head()
#8 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/home1/theriaga...')
#9 /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home1/theriaga...')
#10 /home1/theriaga/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home1/theriaga...')
#11 {main}
  thrown in /home1/theriaga/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 310
```

My understanding is that the function isn't in class-wp-hook.php, so when I put the function in there I get another fatal error.

I am so lost, any help please?

Comment: "When I run it locally (not with PHP but HTML / JS / CSS in one file), it works perfectly." Well that's kind of irrelevant isn't it, seeing as how the PHP which causes the error isn't being run.

Comment: @j08691 Constructive comment, thanks!

Comment: Make sure the file containing the function `enqueue_custom_calculator_assets` is included where it is used.

Comment: Welcome! Did you put this in your current theme's (child or custom) `functions.php`? You can remove the shortcode from this question since the error is the `enqueue_custom_calculator_assets` function. You also don't need to enqueue `jquery` - WP will do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try with anonymous functions

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-calculator-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/Custom/troopRss.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-calculator-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/Custom/troopRss.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
});

add_shortcode('custom_calculator', function() {
    return <<<EOF
<div class="calculator">
    <div class="inputs">

        <div class="total-container">
            <label class ="output-label" for="Food">Food</label>
            <label class ="output-label" for="Wood">Wood</label>
            <label class ="output-label" for="Stone">Stone</label>

            <input type="text" id="Food" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
            <input type="text" id="Wood" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
            <input type="text" id="Stone" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">

            <label class ="output-label" for="Ore">Ore</label>
            <label class ="output-label" for="Gold">Gold</label>
            <label class ="output-label" for="ower">Power</label>

            <input type="text" id="Ore" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
            <input type="text" id="Gold" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
            <input type="text" id="Power" class="output-field-total" readonly placeholder="0">
        </div>
        
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" id="newTroopButton">New Troop</button>

        <div id="troopList"></div>
    </div>
</div>
EOF;
});
```

Keep in mind that with that `wp_enqueue_script`, the scripts are added to every page, also all the pages that do not have the calculator. That's bad for performance, and thus SEO.

If the css is not that much, incorporate it into the global stylesheet. I would load the js file dynamically, you can add code at the bottom of the html for the calculator that checks for a `script` tag with a specific id and if it not exists, creates it, sets its src and adds it to the page. That way it's only loaded when necessary, and non-breaking.
Something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
  .appendChild(
    document.createElement('script')
  )
  .src = filename;
```

An even better way would be to have a script on a hook for every page (e.g. `the_content`) that checks the content, and if the shortcode is in the content, add the js file via `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Make sure then that this script executes before the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook via the priority parameter.